# d3.js queue with multiple json files

Tags: javascript, d3.js, queue

I have this messy and ugly nested json parse calls(!!) which I am trying to simplify, I was hoping with d3.queue. The first json is used by function `doFirstChart` to do a chart after some basic typesetting. The function makes the chart and also returns some extra data which are used together with the second json file and another user-defined parameter by the function `doSecondChart` to do the next chart.

```
    var c = 'someValue'
    d3.json(countryJson, function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Country_Num = +d.Country_Num
            d.y = +d.Y
            d.x = +d.X
        });

       dataOut = doFirstChart(data);

        d3.json(salesJson, function (salesData) {
            salesData.forEach(function (d) {
                d.Expt = +d.Expt
                d.x = +d.x
                d.y = +d.y
            });
            doSecondChart(dataOut, salesData, c)
            console.log("Done!!")
        });
    });
```

It sounds like `d3.queue` is the appropriate tool for these situations,  I have failed however to make it work even with a simplified example. For example (ignoring the exta parameter `c`) the following I was hoping to do trick but obviously I am not using it correctly.

```
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.json, 'path\to\country\data')
.await(doFirstChart)
.defer(d3.json, 'path\to\sales\data')
.await(doSecondChart)
```

I dont even get right the simplest of all:

```
 d3.queue()
 .defer(d3.json, 'path\to\country\data')
 .await(doFirstChart)
```

How is this working please?

Comment: What are you receiving on `doFirstChart()` function? Can you show the function declaration for it? (with it's declared parameters)

Comment: which version of D3 are you using

Comment: @GabrielBalsaCantú: doFirstChart() function takes as argument the data from a json file and renders a scatter plot. Hence it looks like: function sectionChart(data) { // some code }. It returns the location on the Dom where these circles appear ( something like nodes[i].getAttribute('cx') for example)

Comment: @rioV8: version 4.13.0. Havent tried v5, I dont know something will break, havent checked

Comment: d3v5 doesn't have `d3.queue` anymore, use Promises then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *Defer* after *await* is throwing you an error, change this:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, 'path\to\country\data')
  .await(doFirstChart)
  .defer(d3.json, 'path\to\sales\data')
  .await(doSecondChart)
```

To this:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, 'path\to\country\data')
  .defer(d3.json, 'path\to\sales\data')
  .await(splitCharts)
```

Where the function `splitCharts(err, ...args)` is either:

```
function splitCharts(err, ...charts){
    doFirstChart(charts[0]);
    doSecondChart(charts[1]);
}
```

The problem you were having was using defer after and await, and probably your function parameters, where you were not expecting (err, ...args) as parameters.

This example will `console.log` the queue process, so you can work your way from there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function doFirstChart(err, ...args) {
            console.log('[FUNC]: ', args);
        }

        d3.queue()
            .defer(d3.json, 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GbalsaC/db387adae4e84e999960ef79267ceada/raw/0cf2b08280452c7dbb04f81fafcb304bb841bc36/test1.json')
            .defer(d3.json, 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GbalsaC/db387adae4e84e999960ef79267ceada/raw/0cf2b08280452c7dbb04f81fafcb304bb841bc36/test1.json')
            .await(doFirstChart)

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note:*
If you want to pass a custom parameter to the `.await()` callback, you have to define `doFirstChart` function as such:

```
function doFirstChart(myParam){
   // Now you'll return an anonymous function as first step
   return (err, ...args) => {
      // Here you'll do your thing, like rendering the data
      console.log('My Param: ', myParam); // Your Custom param
      console.log('[FUNC]: ', args); // As before
   }
}
```

So, now you can change the `<script></script>` tag to:

```
<script>
    const paramTest = 'Testa Rossa';
    function doFirstChart(myParam) {
        return (err, ...args) => {
         console.log('My Param: ', myParam);
         console.log('[FUNC]: ', args);
        }
    }

    d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GbalsaC/db387adae4e84e999960ef79267ceada/raw/0cf2b08280452c7dbb04f81fafcb304bb841bc36/test1.json')
        .defer(d3.json, 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GbalsaC/db387adae4e84e999960ef79267ceada/raw/0cf2b08280452c7dbb04f81fafcb304bb841bc36/test1.json')
        .await(doFirstChart(paramTest)) // do a first param declaration

</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks!! Do you know how I can pass a used-defined parameter to the await callback please....something like ".await(doFirstChart(myParam))".....which obviously doesnt work

Comment: In that case I'll recommend a nested function for `doFirstChart`,I'll edit my answer to reflect it, don't forget to accept my answer! ;)

Comment: That works like a charm! many many thanks, I couldnt understand the examples on queue. I wouldnt have figure out this in 100 years